# Displaying 'FILTERED' Dataframe in HoverToolTip (Bokeh)

Tags: python, bokeh

In Bokeh(3.2.2) **while trying to display a filtered pandas dataframe  in a Hover tooltip via callback , the cb_data.source/cb_data.x/cb_data.y = undefined .**
How to retrieve current x,y properties in Javascript?

[image]

**ERROR**

```
cb_data.source = undefined
cb_data.value = undefined
cb_data.x/cb_data.y = undefined/undefined
```

**CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

data = {
    "Time": ["12:03", "12:03", "12:03", "12:03", "12:12", "12:12", "12:12", "12:12", "12:17", "12:17", "12:17", "12:17"],
    "Spot": [19653, 19653, 19653, 19653, 19629, 19629, 19629, 19629, 19640, 19640, 19640, 19640],
    "Strike": [19500, 19600, 19700, 19800, 19500, 19600, 19700, 19800, 19500, 19600, 19700, 19800],
    "cLtp": [99, 174, 167, 167, 91, 165, 161, 93, 95, 16, 12, 31],
    "pLtp": [49, 24, 42, 25, 51, 74, 36, 53, 21, 29, 75, 32],
    "cSellOi": [851500, 267500, 379050, 382350, 1324350, 389700, 438850, 1318250, 1365900, 449000, 433200, 433200],
    "pSellOi": [2530350, 1615600, 1656000, 1606500, 2542100, 1598450, 1646950, 2519050, 2544450, 1488200, 1460400, 1460400],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the 'Time' column to datetime
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M')
df.sort_values(by='Time', inplace=True)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

plot = figure(
    x_axis_label="Time",
    y_axis_label="Spot",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    title="Dataframe in Tooltip",
)

plot.line(x='Time', y='Spot', source=source, line_width=3, line_color="blue")

plot.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(
    days="%Y-%m-%d",
    hours="%H:%M:%S",
    minutes="%H:%M"
)

# Create a custom JavaScript callback for the hover tool
jsHover = """
var data = source.data;
var hover = hover;
hover.tooltips = [];
var tooltipString = ""


console.log( "cb_data.source = " + cb_data['source'] );
console.log( "cb_data.value = " + cb_data['value']);
console.log( "cb_data.x/cb_data.y = " + cb_data['x'] +"/" +  cb_data['y']);

for (var i = 0; i < data['Strike'].length; i++) {
    tooltipString += data['Strike'][i] + ": (" + data['cLtp'][i] + ", " + data['pLtp'][i] + ")[";
    tooltipString += data['cSellOi'][i] + ", " + data['pSellOi'][i] + "]\\n";
}

hover.tooltips = tooltipString;

hover.change.emit();
console.log('jsHover Callback Finished');
console.log(hover.tooltips);


hoverTool = HoverTool(tooltips=None)
cb = CustomJS(args={'source': source,'hover': hoverTool}, code=jsHover)
hoverTool.callback = cb
plot.add_tools(hoverTool)
show(plot)
```

"""